# Maya python finding closest vertex to copy deformer map from one geometry to another

Tags: python, maya

I'm trying to copy a deformer's map from one geometry to another based off proximity.

Eg I have sphere1 with 10x10 subdivision and has a radius 1 which has a cluster deformer on it with a painted map that's and another sphere, sphere2 with 30x30 subdivision in the same area but with radius 1.1. I want to apply the same cluster that's affecting sphere1 on sphere2 with the same map. I can't figure out how to get the map over so I figured if I can get the vertices of sphere2 closest to a vertex in sphere1, I can apply that vertex value to sphere2's vertices.

If there is an easier way of doing this, I am all ears. Just couldn't think of any other logic to use in this scenario.

Cheers!!

PS. I have seen a script of the same thing with API but my API knowledge is next to 0 and don't want to use that and not know how to improve on it. I'm trying to learn and not copy paste code without knowing why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this node. You just have to loop sphere1 vertices to the inPosition value and getAttr the closestVertexIndex attribute :
https://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2008help/Nodes/closestPointOnMesh.html

but you will have to make both of your spheres to have the same center

another solution :
another solution could be : if you have the same uvs on spheres, you could be transfering the weight by evaluating uv coordinate. Or even outputing a texture and sampling the picture to get values back on another sphere.

Comment: sorry for the late reply, got caught up on some deadlines. I'll try that out. The spheres were just used as an example, the idea is mainly to be used to tweak geometries in the same area, like a character wearing a tshirt and jacket and you want to tweak a section using the same tweak without having to make more than 1 deformer or apply the same deformer and then have to paint it. So looking to make it efficient and save time.